# Java Spring RequestParam is null

Tags: java, spring

I am having a problem where Spring is giving me RequestParams that are null, even though I believe the Http request contains the variables and is formatted properly.

Here is the bugged code.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{username}/party/{partymember}",method=RequestMethod.PUT,  produces="application/json", consumes="application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public ResponseEntity<String> updatePartyMember(@PathVariable String username, 
                                                @PathVariable String partymember,
                                                @RequestParam(value="membername", required=false) String newMemberName,
                                                @RequestParam(value="job", required=false) String newJob)
```

Here is another function that works properly.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{username}/party", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json", consumes="application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public ResponseEntity<String> addPartyMember(@PathVariable String username, 
                                            @RequestParam(value="membername", required=false) String partyMemberName,
                                            @RequestParam(value="job", required=false) String partyMemberJob)
```

While debugging I took a working query for the second function and changed only the url and request method and I was able to call the first function. This leads me to believe there's nothing wrong with the queries I sent to the server.

Comment: Which is the response from the server? A 404, 400, or something else?

Comment: I'm handling the codes manually. However, if I remove required=false, I get this error "HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'membername' is not present"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring handles request parameters only for GET and POST methods. If you use PUT, you have to pass data by using @RequestBody.

Comment: That doesn't seem like correct behavior. If this is the case, it's probably worth raising at the Spring JIRA.

Comment: There are existing JIRA issues for that. When Spring @RequestParam annotation is used, then parameter is retrieved from request by `HttpServletRequest.getParameter()` and this method doesn't expose parameters when HTTP method is PUT. It's not up to Spring, but Servlet API's implementation. I found information that the cause of this can be that PUT method specification doesn't describe parameters, so maybe that's why Servlet API behaves this way.